# Simple question on parallel transport in dually flat manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

I just started studying [Information Geometry and its applications by Amari](https://www.springer.com/in/book/9784431559771). Right in the first chapter, the author talks about parallel transport in Dually flat manifolds.

Just some quick notation: 
In the first chapter, the author introduces the definition of Manifold $M$ and one of the many coordinate systems on the manifold, say, $\theta$.
The length of the curve from $\boldsymbol {\theta}$ to $\boldsymbol{ \theta + d\theta}$ is given by $$
d s^{2}=2 D_{\psi}[\theta : \theta+d \theta]=\sum g_{i j} d \theta^{i} d \theta^{j}
$$

A tangent vector can be expressed as $$
d \boldsymbol{\theta}=\sum d \theta^{i} \boldsymbol{e}_{i}
$$ where $
\left\{\boldsymbol{e}_{i}\right\}
$, $i \in \{1,.. ,n\}$ are the basis of the tangent space of M at point  $\boldsymbol \theta$. Similarly, the author introduces a dual affine coordinate system whose corresponding basis is $\left\{e^{* i}\right\}$. Therefore,we can write

$$
d \boldsymbol \theta^{*}=\sum d \theta_{i}^{*} e^{* i}
$$

Now, one can also write the length of the small line vector as $$
d s^{2}=\langle d \boldsymbol{\theta}, d \boldsymbol{\theta}\rangle= g_{i j} d \theta^{i} d \theta^{j}
$$, which is rewritten as $$
d s^{2}=\left\langle d \theta^{i} e_{i}, d \theta^{j} e_{j}\right\rangle=\left\langle e_{i}, e_{j}\right\rangle d \theta^{i} d \theta^{j}
$$
Hence, it is clear that $$
g_{i j}(\boldsymbol{\theta})=\left\langle\boldsymbol{e}_{i}, \boldsymbol{e}_{j}\right\rangle
$$

Similarly, for the dual affine coordinate system $\boldsymbol \theta^*$, we have $$
g^{* i j}(\boldsymbol \theta^*)=\left\langle e^{* i}, e^{* j}\right\rangle
$$

If $\bf G$ is the Jacobian of the transformation from $\boldsymbol \theta$ to $\boldsymbol \theta^*$, then we can write 
$$
\begin{array}{l}{d \boldsymbol{\theta}^{*}=\mathbf{G} d \boldsymbol{\theta}, \quad d \boldsymbol{\theta}=\mathbf{G}^{-1} d \boldsymbol{\theta}^{*}} \\ {d \theta_{i}^{*}=g_{i j} d \theta^{j}, \quad d \theta^{j}=g^{* j i} d \theta_{i}^{*}}\end{array}
$$

> Actual doubt:
>
> If a tangent vector $\mathbf{A} = A^i\mathbf{e_i} $ is transported
>   from a point $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ to $\boldsymbol{\theta^{'}}$, the
>   components $A^i$ remain the same because $\mathbf{e_i}$ is same
>   everywhere in a dually flat manifold. However, in the later
>   paragraphs, it is stated that the length of the vector is not constant
>   even in this dually flat manifold. If the components and basis remain
>   the same, shouldn't it be the case where even the length of the vector
>   is also the same when moved from one point to another point?
>
> Also, why is dual parallel transport any different parallel transport?
>   After all, they are just two different coordinate systems. Because, it
>   is given that the manifold is dually flat, so both the coordinate
>   systems remain the same across all the points. So, why does the
>   parallel transport makes the vector invariant under the original basis
>   but the same parallel transport changes the vector in the dual basis? 
>   Any intuitive explanations, illustrations or examples on how this
>   happens?

P.S: Relevant page from the book. 
[image]

Comment: Offhand this sounds like a lot of nonsense to me. What connection is the author using? Not the Levi-Civita connection. And the vector doesn't live both in the vector space and in its dual.

Comment: @TedShifrin The author has not introduced Levi-Civita connection yet. Can you please explain why you say that a vector cannot live in its vector and dual space? After all, here, dual space is nothing but a different coordinate system.

Comment: @TedShifrin related thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491049/for-riemannian-manifolds-what-does-it-mean-to-express-a-vector-using-the-dual-b
OP, I'm reading the same book/similar resource where they do the same thing; the answer is that when they say "dual", they're conceptually talking about translating an actual covector back to a vector, using the metric isomorphism

Comment: @hamburglar Yes, it’s become clear recently that certain applied fields and authors are using what is non-standard terminology for those of us trained in “pure” differential geimetry.

Answer (score 4):

In information geometry there are two flat connections $\nabla^e$ and $\nabla^m$ that are dual with respect to the Fisher-Rao metric $g$, which means that for any three vector fields $X,Y,Z$ we have
$$X g(Y,Z)=g(\nabla^e_XY,Z)+g(Y,\nabla^m_XZ).$$
A consequence of this is that if $Y$ is e-parallel along $X$ and $Z$ is m-parallel along $X$, then the angle between $Y$ and $Z$ is constant. However, this is not true if both $Y$ and $Z$ are parallel along $X$ wrt. to one connection only.
The duality above is different from the property enjoyed by the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^{\text{LC}}$, which satisfies
$$X g(Y,Z)=g(\nabla^{\text{LC}}_XY,Z)+g(Y,\nabla^{\text{LC}}_XZ)$$
for all vector fields $X,Y,Z$.
This is known as self-dualilty or metricity of $\nabla^{\text{LC}}$ and can also be written as $\nabla^{\text{LC}}g=0$ since for any arbitrary connection $\nabla$ we have
$$X g(Y,Z)=g(\nabla_XY,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_XZ)+(\nabla_X g)(Y,Z).$$
In contrast, $\nabla^eg$ and $\nabla^mg$ are both non-zero.

Since $\nabla^{\text{LC}}$ is not flat, parallel transport is complicated in general. On the other hand, $\nabla^e$ and $\nabla^m$ are flat, so parallel transport is easy. There are sets of dual charts $\theta^i$ and $\eta_i$ that are e- and m-affine, respectively. Dual means that if we denote $e_i=\partial_i=\partial_{\theta^i}$ and $e^i=\partial^i=\partial_{\eta^i}$
$$g(e_i, e^j)=\delta^j_i \Leftrightarrow e^i=g^{ij}e_j\Leftrightarrow e_i=g_{ij}e^j.$$
Affine means that all the Christoffel symbols vanish in that chart, i.e. all Christoffel symbols of $\nabla^e$ vanish in the $\theta$ chart and all Christoffel symbols of $\nabla^m$ vanish in the $\eta$ chart. This in turn implies that parallel transport corresponds to constant coefficients in the respective charts. I.e. $\partial_i$ are e-parallel and $\partial^i$ are m-parallel. The property $g(\partial_i,\partial^j)=\delta^j_i$ reflects the above self-duality condition.