# For Riemannian manifolds, what does it mean to express a vector using the dual basis?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, dual-spaces

I've read most of Lee's *Smooth Manifolds* and also his *Intro to Riemannian Manifolds*. In Lee's books, for a manifold $M$, he defines a tangent vector $v \in T_p M$ as a derivation at a point $p$, i.e., a linear map that maps real-valued functions $f \in C^\infty (M)$ to a real number: $v: C^\infty (M) \rightarrow \mathbb R$. And I'm not sure if it's necessarily has to be of this form, but he seems to identify them earlier by the fact that a tangent vector $v$ yields a map $D_v|_p: C^\infty (M) \rightarrow \mathbb R$, the directional  derivative of a function $f$.

He also defines tangent *covectors* as linear functionals on the tangent space at a point $p$, i.e., if the tangent space is a vector space $V$, then the covector space $V^*$ is the set of linear maps $\omega: V \rightarrow \mathbb R$, and the basis $E_j$ and dual basis $\epsilon_i$ of the vector/covector spaces are orthogonal in the usual way: $\langle  \epsilon_i , E_j \rangle = \epsilon_i (E_j) = \delta^i_j$.

That all makes sense to me, but I'm conceptually confused by other things I saw. E.g., in *An Elementary Introduction to Information Geometry* (p5) by Frank Nielsen, the author says:

[image]
[image]
and:
[image]

I read this to mean that a given vector $v$ can be expressed using either its primal basis ($e_i$) or its dual basis ($e^i$), in Einstein notation:

$$v = v^i e_i = v_i e^i$$

What I don't understand is how $v$ can be expressed with either basis, given that the basis of the primal space are vectors, while the basis of the dual space are covectors! the way I read it in the Lee books were that vectors and covectors are different entities, which do different things.

My best guess is that it somehow involves using the isomorphism the metric provides between a basis and its dual, e.g., $e^i = g^{ij} e_j$, but I don't see how that gets around the fact that $v$ still must be a *vector* in the end.

How can a vector be expressed using both the primal or dual bases?

edit: and with regards to the last picture, I'm even more confused: my understanding (and what he says) is that the metric $g$ is a mapping $V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb R$, and that defines an isomorphism that basically allows us to translate between vectors and covectors, i.e., $g: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb R \Rightarrow g: V \rightarrow (V \rightarrow \mathbb R) \Rightarrow g: V \rightarrow V^\ast$. And that's what he appears to be doing in eq's 7 and 8, but it's translating between $e_i$ and $e^{\ast j}$, which seem to be both vectors...

Comment: When quoting a book you should provide a full quote, as well a reference to page number and the edition number. Given what you wrote, most likely, what is meant is that every **covector** can be written as $v_ie^i$. But, without a full quote, it's hard to tell.

Comment: your guess is correct

Comment: The “something else” you were reading (or watching) has caused plenty of confusion here recently.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, good point, I added the source, thanks.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry I didn't mean to be mysterious! I added a source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Lee is a pure mathematician, while Nielsen is an applied mathematician. As it frequently happens with applied mathematicians, Nielsen is loose with terminology. He also made one typo in the quoted passage. His use of notation is also different from Lee's (whose notation are more standard).

In more detail: Nielsen does not explain which space the objects called $e^{*i}$ belong to, but, from the context, they belong to the vector space $V$ (the tangent space) and not $V^*$ (the cotangent space). I assume, he also uses (elsewhere in the book?) genuine covectors $e^i\in V^*$. In his picture, however, he forgot to put $*$ in $e^i$ (this would be a typo). The relation between $e^{*i}\in V$ and $e^i\in V^*$  then would be that
$$
\langle e^{*i}, v\rangle= e^i(v)$$
for every $v\in V$. However, it is also possible that he simply refuses to use actual covectors (differential 1-forms) in the book and leaves it unexplained what the symbols $dx^i$ stand for (if he ever uses differential forms in the book).

He notes (correctly) that when
$$
v=\sum_i v^i e_i= \sum_i v_ie^{*i},
$$
one can recover the coefficients $v^i$ and $v_i$ using the inner product in $V$:
$$
v^i= \langle v, e^{*i}\rangle
$$
$$
v_i= \langle v, e_i\rangle
$$

Edit. Regarding your question in the edit. The Riemannian metric defines "[musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism)" isomorphisms between tangent and cotangent spaces
$$
\flat: T_pM\to T^*_pM, \sharp: T^*_pM\to T_pM. 
$$
(One should not call these isomorphisms $g$.) What he (Nielsen) is using is that $\sharp(e^i)=e^{*i}$ and **not** that $\sharp(e^{*i})=e_{i}$ (the latter would be nonsense indeed). Here, I am using the notation $\{e^i: i=1,...,n\}$ for the basis of $V^*$ which is dual to the basis $\{e_i: i=1,...,n\}$ of $V$. Admittedly, he never introduced the notation $e^i$, but this is what he is implicitly using.

Comment: hi and thanks for the help. What you're saying makes sense; I guess I forgot that, like in his picture, the "dual" basis vectors $e^{*j}$ there would satisfy the $\langle e_i, e^{*j} \rangle = \delta_i^j$, and I see that when defined this way, those coefficients are equal to that. But I'm adding an edit to the OP, because then it still seems like what he said doesn't make sense, if you could possibly take a look at it? thank you for your help either way.

Comment: @hamburglar: No, his picture is correct apart from the missing stars. The point is that a nondegenerate bilinear form (say, an inner product) determines an isomorphism $V\to V^*$. (It is a good exercise to figure out why; look closely at my answer and you will see the formula for that isomorphism.) This is what he is using.

Comment: hi @moishe, thank you again for the further clarifications, I get it now! I was familiar with the "musical isomorphisms" from Lee's book, but it's clearer what Nielsen is doing now. I'm still a bit confused about a few parts. First, why he even does this -- why work with these $e^{\ast i}$ vectors, which are essentially the covectors $e^i$ "translated", rather than just the covectors $e^i$? more generally, I'm confused by the fact that he seems to use the words "dual/reciprocal" for the $e^{\ast i}$, which I guess makes sense because they're mutually ortho, but they're not in the dual space...

Comment: 1. One can only speculate: Maybe he expects his readers to have hard time digesting dual vector spaces. 2. In the pages that you posted, he uses only the terminology "reciprocal" (not "dual") for the vectors  $e^{*i}$. I did not see this terminology in pure math literature.

Comment: thank you again!