# What does the dual parallel transport, or conjugate affine connection, actually do?

Tags: differential-geometry, information-geometry

I'm reading both Frank Nielsen's *An Elementary Introduction to Information Geometry* as well as Amari's *Information geometry and its applications*, and confused by something they use (I'll focus on AEITIG here).

He first introduces the concept of an affine connection $\nabla$, which is basically a covariant derivative on vector fields, so if we have vector fields $X, Y$, it tells us how to calculate $\nabla_X Y$, i.e., how $Y$ changes as we move in the $X$ direction, at each point. If we have the basis $(\partial_i) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})$ for a smooth chart $(U, x)$, then exactly what the connection does is defined in terms of the Christoffel symbols:

$\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j = \Gamma_{ij}^k \partial_k$

This all makes sense to me. Then, from what I understand, if we want to transport a vector from the tangent plane at one point to another, we could do some sort of integration of that derivative over the path taken, and that would give the final vector.

He then introduces (section 3) the concept of a conjugate connection $\nabla^\ast$ that's conjugate to a given connection $\nabla$. He mentions a few properties of it, like an identity that must be satisfied for it to be conjugate, but never what it actually does or how to figure it out. Here's that identity:
[image]

What I don't understand is the following:

1. *What does the conjugate connection actually do to a vector*? I.e., for the regular connection, it's clear that it's saying how it's changing the basis vectors.
2. Given a connection $\nabla$, how does one actually find the conjugate $\nabla^\ast$?

I have a couple guesses but they're only that. My guess for (1) is that if the primal connection tells us how the basis vectors change, $\nabla_{\partial_i} \partial_j$, then maybe the conjugate one tells us how the reciprocal basis vectors $\partial^i$ change, i.e., $\nabla_{\partial^i} \partial^j$. This is somewhat complicated by the fact that (like [I asked about in my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491049/for-riemannian-manifolds-what-does-it-mean-to-express-a-vector-using-the-dual-b)) his dual basis isn't the covector dual basis $dx_i$ I'm used to from earlier differential geometry, it's the dual (covector) basis with the "sharp" operator applied to it, making it a vector again, such that we have two ways of expressing the same **vector**.

For (2), I'm even less sure, but he notes that if we have a pair of conjugate connections $\nabla, \nabla^\ast$ that are coupled with the metric connection $g$, then the mean connection must equal the Levi-Civita connection, so

$\nabla^{LC} = \overline \nabla = \frac{\nabla + \nabla^\ast}{2}$

Since we can figure out the Christoffel symbols of the LC connection from the metric $g$, it seems like given the symbols defining $\nabla$, we could figure out an explicit form for $\nabla^\ast$. Is this right, or is there an easier way?

Comment: I assume that you mean $\partial^i=g^{ij}\partial_j$ (the dual basis from sharping $dx^i$. If so then one can compute $\nabla_{\partial^i} \partial^k ={\tilde{\Gamma}^{ik}}_j\partial^j$ using the product rule for $\nabla$ and $C^\infty$ linearity property to relate the connection coefficients ${\tilde{\Gamma}^{ik}}_j$ to the coefficients of $\nabla$. This determines $\nabla^*$ uniquely. Also I think the Levi-Civita connection equality only holds if $\nabla$ was metric compatible to start.

Comment: hi @BaselJ., thanks for the help. I think I meant what you said -- the vectors $\partial_i$ and covectors $dx^i$ (the actual coordinate bases) are determined by the chart being used, but he (implicitly) uses the tangent-cotangent isomorphism induced by $g$ to turn $dx^i$ into the corresponding vector, which I'm calling $\partial^i$ here (superscript despite the fact that it's a vector, since it's "reciprocal/dual"). so I think this verifies what I suspected for (1), that $\nabla^\ast$ is defined by $\nabla_{\partial^i} \partial^j$, right?

Comment: I think I understand how to find the $\Gamma$ coefficients in the way you said. but I'm not sure what you mean about the LC connection part -- doesn't the LC always exist for a metric? and the identity he says must be satisfied for $\nabla, \nabla^\ast$ to be conjugate is $X \langle Y, Z \rangle = \langle \nabla_X Y, Z \rangle +  \langle Y, \nabla_X^\ast Z \rangle$. So I took that to mean that neither of $\nabla, \nabla^\ast$ are metric compatible on their own, but they must satisfy that identity and are related to the LC connection via the mean connection $\bar \nabla$?

Comment: I think the "identity that it must satisfy in order to be conjugate" is the key part of this question and should be included in the body of the post, together with those "other properties" you mention. Otherwise we know even less than you, since not all of us have the book.

Comment: Are the connections assumed to be torsion free?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz the paper is open access so getting access to it shouldn't be a problem, but I've edited to add the identity.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz they say "In information geometry, we consider a pair of conjugate affine connections $\nabla, \nabla^\ast$ (often but not necessarily torsion-free) ..." so I think it's not an assumption for the definitions here.

Comment: Oh, I see. Somehow I misunderstood the first line of your post and thought it was a book. I'll have a look at the paper. Anyway, it's better if the question is self-contained, so thanks for the edit.

Comment: The scalar product $⟨Y,Z⟩=g(Y,Z)$ can be thought of as a triple product. Thus $X⟨Y,Z⟩=(∇_Xg)(Y,Z)+g(∇_XY,Z)+g(Y,∇_XZ)$. Two terms of this are linear in the unchanged $Y$, these get combined to $(∇_Xg)(Y,Z)+g(Y,∇_XZ)=g(Y,∇^*_XZ)$. (This might be circular, if one defines $(∇_Xg)$ via this same product rule.) One would now have to check if the use of "conjugate" is appropriate, that the conjugate of the conjugate is again the original.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz haha sorry, I don't actually know what to call it, since I thought it's a paper, but even if it is, it's 61 pages, which is practically a small book :P

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes, he has that definition right below the one I posted (in the paper), but it doesn't really clear up what $\nabla^\ast$ itself does.

Comment: I think the idea is more reflection than duality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(e_i)$ be a local orthonormal frame (so that $\left< e_i, e_j \right> = \delta_{ij}$). Write $\nabla_{e_i} e_j = \Gamma_{ij}^k e_k$ and $\nabla^{*}_{e_i} e_j = \tilde{\Gamma}_{ij}^k e_k$. Plugging $X = e_i, Y = e_j, Z = e_k$ into the defining equation of the conjugate connection, we get that
$$ 0 = e_i \left< e_j, e_k \right> = \left< \nabla_{e_i} e_j, e_k \right>
+ \left< e_j, \nabla^{*}_{e_i} e_k \right> = \Gamma_{ij}^k + \tilde{\Gamma}_{ik}^j. $$
Hence, if you know the coefficients of $\nabla$ with respect to an **orthonormal frame** you can easily compute the coefficients of $\nabla^{*}$ with respect to the same frame by the formula $\tilde{\Gamma}_{ik}^j = -\Gamma_{ij}^k$. In particular, you also see that $\nabla^{**} = \nabla$ as expected.

Working with orthonormal frame allows you also to see that the conjugate connection $\nabla^{*}$ is in fact equal to the dual connection $\nabla^{\sharp}$ if you identify vectors and covectors using the metric. More explicitly, let $e^i$ be the dual basis of the frame $(e_i)$. Since $(e_i)$ is orthonormal, the dual frame $(e^i)$ is identified with the frame $(e_i)$ under the musical isomorphisms. The dual connection $\nabla^{\sharp}$ is defined by the similar equation
$$ X \{ \omega, Z \} = \{\nabla^{\sharp}_X(\omega), Z \} + \{ \omega, \nabla_X Z \} $$
where $X,Z$ are vectors fields, $\omega$ is a covector field and $\{ \cdot, \cdot \}$ is the natural pairing (i.e $\{ \omega, Z \} = \omega(Z)$).
Plugging in $X = e_i, Z = e_j$ and $\omega = e^k$ and using the fact that $\{ \omega, Z \} = e^k(e_j) = \delta^k_j$ is constant, one immediately gets that
$$ 0 = \{ \nabla^{\sharp}_{e_i}(e^k), e_j \} + \{ e^k, \nabla_{e_i} e_j \} = 
\{ \nabla^{\sharp}_{e_i}(e^k), e_j \} + \Gamma_{ij}^k. $$
Hence
$$\nabla^{\sharp}_{e_i}(e^k) = \{ \nabla^{\sharp}_{e_i}(e_k), e_j \}e^j = -\Gamma_{ij}^k e^j $$
so the coefficients of the dual connection with respect to the coframe $e^i$ are also given by the same formula.

Comment: thank you, incredibly helpful. I skimmed it and it makes sense so far but I'm going to read it more carefully and come back with questions. I think part of what confused me is that I assumed that $\nabla^\ast$ was a connection that can only act on (and with respect to) the $e^{\ast i}$ vectors (sharped $e^i$ covectors), but with your answer I realize that doesn't really make sense; they're still vectors, just a different basis, and just connections acting on/with respect to vectors, right?

Comment: @hamburglar: Yeah, you're correct. Both $\nabla$ and $\nabla^{*}$ act on vector fields. There is some analogy with linear algebra: Given a linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow V$, one can always talk about the dual map $T \colon V^{*} \rightarrow V^{*}$. If the vector space $V$ carries an inner product (i.e, a metric) then one can use the metric to identify $V$ and $V^{*}$ and get an adjoint map $T^{*} \colon V \rightarrow V$ (which will depend on the metric on $V$). The same happens with connections: Given a connection $\nabla$ which acts on vector fields, one can always talk about the

Comment: dual connection $\nabla^{\sharp}$ which acts on covector fields. When there is a metric around, one can identify covectors and vectors and get a "dual connection" $\nabla^{*}$ which acts on vector fields (just like $\nabla$).

Comment: hi, I took a look again and at the moment it seems clear enough to me. I realized in Lee's Riemannian manifolds book, he actually covers the equation for $X \langle \omega, Z \rangle$, but he just uses the notation of $\nabla$ rather than $\nabla^\sharp$ (and regular inner product brackets despite them not being an inner product). Do you have another good resource you learned this from? I think I confused myself more by trying to grok parallel transport in the same question, but I'll make another question for that soon... thank you very much again!

Comment: @ham burglar: I've never seen the version $\nabla^{*}$ which you asked about before. All the references I know (for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Dual_connection) define a dual connection to be a connection which acts on covectors and use the notation $\nabla^{*}$ (or even just $\nabla$, relying on context not to confuse it with the original connection). I used $\nabla^{\sharp}$ so that it won't override your notation but this is not standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer.

Take two connections $\nabla,\nabla^*$. Each connection has its own Christoffel symbols
$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j
&= \Gamma^r_{ij}\partial_r \\
\nabla^*_{\partial_i}\partial_j
&= \Gamma^{*r}_{ij}\partial_r \\
\end{align}$$
which determine it completely.

Now take a connection $\nabla$ and let $\nabla^*$ be its conjugate with respect to $g$. In components, the equation
$$X(g(Y,Z)) = g(\nabla_XY,Z)+g(Y,\nabla^*_XZ) \tag 1$$
looks like
$$\partial_i g_{jk} = g_{rk}\Gamma^r_{ij}+g_{jr}\Gamma^{*r}_{ik}$$
so you can solve for $\Gamma^*$ as
$$g_{jr}\Gamma^{*r}_{ik} = \partial_i g_{jk} - g_{rk}\Gamma^r_{ij}$$
$$\Gamma^{*s}_{ik} = g^{js}(\partial_i g_{jk} - g_{rk}\Gamma^r_{ij}).$$

Now from the defining equation $(1)$ you can show that the mean connection $\bar\nabla=\frac 1 2 (\nabla+\nabla^*)$ is metric compatible, i.e. $\bar\nabla g=0$. What is not so clear to me is that $\bar\nabla$ has zero torsion. I'll think about it.

Comment: thanks, this seems like a straightforward way of finding the components of $\nabla^\ast$. Later, he uses $\nabla^\ast$ for dual parallel transport, where we transport two vectors $u, v$ over the same path, but transport $u$ using $\nabla$ and transport $v$ using $\nabla^\ast$. My impression is that expressing each in their primal or "dual" ways and then using that connection to transport it leads to much simpler math. I bring this up because I'm wondering if it makes sense to define $\nabla^\ast$ instead by its action on and w.r.t the reciprocal basis vectors $\partial^i$.